# Role of openstack running kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openstack

I want to understand the role of openstack when kubernetes is deployed on top of it. Will the user be able to access the underlying openstack layer in this case? (I mean to ask if user can create instances, networks and access any other openstack resource)Or will the user be only provided with Kubernetes offerings? Any link or answer would help.
I don't seem to find the functionality part mentioned in any guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openstack's role in the k8s world is to provide k8s with instances and storage to do it's job, just like GCE and Azure.

Kubernetes tries to abstract underlying cloud infrastructure so applications can be ported from one cloud provider to another transparently.

k8s achieves this by defining abstractions like persistent volumes and persistent volume claims allowing a pod to define a requirement for storage without needing to state it requires a cinder volume directly.

There should be no need to access openstack directly from your kubernetes-based app unless you app needs to actually manage an openstack cluster in which case you can provide your openstack credentials to your app and access the openstack api.

Comment: Basically in my cloud, I want to provide users access to openstack and kubernetes deployed on top of openstack. In case of kubernetes, if i have understood you correctly, user should be only allowed to access kubernetes and not the underlying openstack. But if the user wants to access only openstack then he should be allowed access to it. Am I making any sense?

Comment: yes I understand. You want to offer either IAAS or k8sAAS depending on the users requirements. If your customer wants k8s you have two options: point them to the documentation on rolling out k8s on openstack https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/openstack-heat/ OR provide them with a ready-made kubernetes solution. I did not have much success running the heat-based k8s solution, I ended up doing my own openstack solution. The expectation out there right now is that k8s is spun up using a nice dialog and no underlying infrastructure is exposed

Comment: Oh ok thanks a lot for that explanation.Yes  even I am not very keen on setting up kubernetes with Heat, Murano or magnum. I want to provide them with a ready-made k8s solution. Any suggestion on how i can set it up on openstack otherwise?

Comment: I actually used my own heat template based off the heat template referenced in the heat guide. The best source of info for me was the CoreOS guide for rolling out k8s: https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/ you get a very good understanding of what makes k8s work in the process and you save a heck of a lot of time too (although it doesn't appear so on first glance)

Comment: I have ubuntu as my OS. Would that be an issue?

Comment: no, you would have to figure out how to run etcd, flannel and the kubelet wrapper on ubuntu. but since you're on openstack can't you just spin up CoreOS instances?

Comment: Yea maybe I'll do that. Thanks :)